# Changing server mail address (hostname?) on VPS (parallels, plesk)

Tags: domain-name-system, email, hostname

My VPS came with a default domain (lets say http://vpsname.com), which was very random long domain name. This VPS hosts two websites, lets call them websiteA.co.uk and websiteB.co.uk.

At the moment mail gets sent from vpsname.com, even if I use an authenticated email system emails get classified as Spam since they don't come from the matching domain name.

The server runs Virtuozzo, Plesk, Parallels etc, and an Apache PHP server.

I want to change http://vpsname.com to vps.websiteA.co.uk

Do I just superuser and change the hostname, or is it more complicated than that?

I access the VPS by IP, so I am not worried about URL access as such, I just need email to be sent from websiteA.co.uk

Can anybody provide me with any advice, I am new to VPS's...

Thanks a lot

Adam

Comment: do you have ssh and is it postfix mail?

Comment: Yes and Yes. I have full access to the VPS (including physical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instructions [here](http://www.keithdmitchell.com/2008/10/31/changing-plesk-email-hostnamehostname/) Also be sure to have a PTR record for the IP and setup a SPF record to help with spam catchers. You should run the IP through a RBL checker also and make sure its clean. I like MX tool boxes tool [here](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)

Comment: Jacob, thank you for the quick response. I have followed the first set of instructions and it has certainly changed the contents of the email headers, which was one of my key hopes. I have checked the RBL and I am clean on that front. I need to sort out PTR and SPF still but so far so good. Thank you for the quick and accurate help.

Comment: no problem, I suggest highly\ doing a PTR and SPF also as they can help greatly.